# Authentication spring rest service in java [server side]

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring project which exposes some api to others but they need to authenticate to use the service.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

When i use this spring configuration am able to authenticate and use the service using the client project below

```
public void getRestValue() {
        final String url = "http://localhost:8080/template/getData";
        final String username = "admin@admin.com";
        final String password = "admin";
        // Populate the HTTP Basic Authentitcation header with the username and
        // password
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String plainCreds = username + ":" + password;
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
        System.out.println(response);
        String account = response.getBody();
        System.out.println(account);
    }
```

but when i use the below configuration using my userservice getting values from DB i get the login page as response

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AppUserDetailsService appUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(appUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/setup/*")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password").failureUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }
}
```

Please tell me where am going wrong

Comment: What does the debug log say?

Comment: As soon as i call the rest service i get the login page html in the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Your client uses HTTP Basic authentication but your server is only configured for form authentication. Try adding `.httpBasic()` in your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.

Comment: I tried adding that too.in that case even the authentication which was available also got disabled when i tried in browser.